# Error: An error occurred while skipping data rows

Tags: ssis-2012

I am getting these errors in flat file connection manager.

> Error: [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Flat File Source returned error code 0xC0202091.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

I am reletively new to *ssis* and I am finding it quite hard to figure out the issue. Please let me know your views.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS mysterious error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233571/ssis-mysterious-error)

Answer (score 29):

On your flat file connection properties - Look for the property "*AlwaysCheckForRowDelimiters*" - SET it to `FALSE`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: While this didn't fix the failure itself, it did allow the package to progress slightly further and provide a more useful error message (in my case, a couple of columns had been removed from the CSV source file without my knowledge). Once I had fixed that issue, I was able to set AlwaysCheckForRowDelimiters back to `TRUE`

Comment: Helped me too. Since dts on through, the simplest of tasks seemed to have gotten progressively harder in SSIS...yo wrong direction :\

Comment: this actually fixed this issue for me. thanks a lot @desoxx.

Comment: This did not work for me. How I fixed it was to remove an extra column in my SSIS that does not exist in my CSV file (somebody added an extra column into the flat source connection manager of an existing SSIS project)

Comment: Oh my god thank you! I worked on my package for hours and this problem finally was solved!

Answer (score 2):

"An error occurred while skipping data rows" - I had this error in a package and found the problem was reading files inside a for loop. More files matched the criteria than intended, so a file with an invalid schema was also matched.

More generally I think this is related to either the file not matching the connection definition, I have also seen people online saying it is related to the flat file using a text qualifier (i.e. " in a csv) but having no closing quote.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the source file had changed and had one column less than before, which resulted in this error.

(I had to update the definition of the source and update the mappings to fix it.)

Answer (score 0):

I had this error today, and my package was looking for more files than existed based on the conditions of the for each loop. The text qualifier wasn't the issue causing this particular error.

Answer (score 0):

1. near the **Start** button press drop-down menu arrow
2. choose ***package_name* Debug Properties**
3. than under **Configuration Properties** open **Debugging**
4. than under **Debug Options** choose **Run64BitRuntime** and turn it to **False**

Answer (score 0):

I had to rebuild the csv connection in SSIS which fixed the issue.