# Error Occurred while skipping data rows

Tags: sql, ssis

### I'm having a problem with a flat file source in that the package throws an error straight away. The error I get is as follows:

Error: An error occurred while skipping data rows.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Non Universal returned error code 0xC0202091.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

[Universal [1351]] Error: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Universal returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233571/ssis-mysterious-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS mysterious error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233571/ssis-mysterious-error)